# Remove remainder of string after first encountered non-alphanumeric character (keep all leading space-delimited "words")

Tags: php, string, truncate

How do I cut off the above strings at first non-alphanumeric character using a regular expression (ideally with no lingering trailing spaces after the truncation)?

The non-alphanumeric characters will not be known in advance but they might be a hyphen, a comma, an opening parenthesis, etc.  I only want to keep the leading words prior to the symbol.

Input strings:

- `iPhone 7 plus - space grey (New)`
- `iPhone6 plus, brand new, (Used)`
- `iPhone 5 ( black)`

Desired results:

- `iPhone 7 plus`
- `iPhone6 plus`
- `iPhone 5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the second part, just match the first:

```
preg_match('/[A-Z0-9\s]+/i', $string, $match);
echo $match[0];
```

Match letters `A-Z`, numbers `0-9` and spaces `\s` one or more times `+` case-insensitive `i`.

Comment: `$s = 'Apple iphone 6 64gb verizon wireless 4g lte - space gray silver gold';
$ex = preg_match('/[A-Z0-9s]+/i', $s, $match);
print_r($match);` this returns me just `Apple` for given string on PHP version 5.6.19. while i checked same code on [onlinePhpEditor](http://www.writephponline.com/) this gives me expected results. Idk why?

Comment: my mistake, online editor is skipping \ from **\s**. your code is OK.

Comment: You can just replace `\s` with a space if needed.

Answer (score 4):

A simple preg_match should do the trick.

```
preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/", $str, $match);
```

It will match words (a-Z), numbers and spaces, more than one.

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/kW8

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to do it.

```
$input = 'iPhone6 plus, brand new, (Used)';
$items = preg_split('/[^A-Za-z0-9\s]/i', $input);
echo $items[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

**All other posted answers fail to trim the potential whitespace before the delimiting symbol**, so the output strings are not as clean as they should be.  `preg_match()` and `preg_split() are less direct tools because they create an array from which the first element must be accessed.

More accurately, your task should be described as "How to trim the trailing characters starting from the first occurrence of a listed character?". When restated in that manner, it is clear that splitting/exploding the input string into an array is an unnecessary step before returning the leading substring.

Most literally, you want to replace the unwanted portion of the string with an empty string.

For the cleanest output string, additional consideration is involved to remove the optional space before the first occurrence of a listed character.  This avoids an extra `rtrim()` call after replacing.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VYCSq))

```
$strings = [
    'iPhone 7 plus - space grey (New)',
    'iPhone6 plus, brand new, (Used)',
    'iPhone 5 ( black)',
];

var_export(preg_replace('~ ?[-,(].*~', '', $strings));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'iPhone 7 plus',
  1 => 'iPhone6 plus',
  2 => 'iPhone 5',
)
```

(For the record, `preg_replace()` works the same when fed a string instead of an array as in my demo)

Pattern:

```
 ?     # match zero or one literal space (there is a space before the question mark)
[-,(]  # match one of the listed characters
.*     # match zero or more characters to the end of the string/line
```

Or if you don't want a blacklist of characters, use a whitelist in a negated character class. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eEWo2))

```
var_export(preg_replace('~ ?[^ [:alnum:]].*~', '', $strings));
```